# WMS Request with Authentication in Leaflet from Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms

I am having no luck requesting a WMS layer on a Leaflet map that is password protected in Geoserver. The layer loads fine in Leaflet when authenticated in Geoserver portal on another tab, but once I logout of the Geoserver portal on another tab, the WMS request no longer works since the layer no longer loads.

The layer is part of a read-only group with the following data security rules (which are all default)

> privatedata.*.r  Role_Student,ROLE_AUTHENTICATED,GROUP_ADMIN,ADMIN

I make the call for the WMS layer in Leaflet using the following:

```
    var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://username:password@IP_ADDRESS:8080/geoserver/ows?', {
        layers: 'privatedata:layer1',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
    attribution: "bla bla bla"
}).addTo(mymap);
```

where username is replaced with my username, password with the correct password, and IP_ADDRESS with the IP address of my server. For some reason this does not work. The map loads but the WMS layer does not load.

If I navigate to the service request URL, I get the following:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://159.203.11.246:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="service">
<ows:ExceptionText>No service: ( ows )</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Are there any specific requirements on the Geoserver side to get protected layers to load -- keep in mind I have not changed any of the default authentication settings? How can I get WMS layers to load in Leaflet that require authentication?

UPDATE:

I tested the wms layer call on a local Geoserver and it worked find with authentication, but the cloud-based server is still not working. I check the Geoserver log (below) but not sure how to interpret the results:

> 2017-03-26 17:06:40,489 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
>   org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Could not find layer test:test_layer
>       at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.parseLayers(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:1337)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:236)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:85)
>       at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestKVP(Dispatcher.java:1514)
>       at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:680)
>       at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:258)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>       at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: which authentication method have you set -http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/auth/providers.html

Comment: I'm using the default "Basic username/password authentication" provider.

Comment: And note that the user/password authentication works in QGIS for WMS layers, just not in Leaflet.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using a recent Chrome browser to access your leaflet web application and you pass the credentials as URL parameters, then probably chrome will block that as a safety precaution. You might give a try in another browser. However, it is (very) bad practice to expose the uname/pw in client side javascript (so +1 for Chrome to block it).